# Network timeout when device in doze / standby mode

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to post to my server using volley and GCMNetworkManager. If the screen is on the network tasks complete with no errors. As soon as the device goes in to doze / standby mode then they all timeout.

```
OneoffTask task = new OneoffTask.Builder()
                    .setService(UpdaterService.class)
                    .setTag(TASK_TAG_UPDATE)
                    .setUpdateCurrent(true)
                    .setExecutionWindow(0, 30)
                    .setRequiredNetwork(Task.NETWORK_STATE_CONNECTED)
                    .setExtras(data)
                    .build();

mGcmNetworkManager.schedule(task);
```

Comment: Have you tried these resources provided by the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html)?

Comment: Yes, I read through it several times.